# Will "in:CHATS" queries continue working in the Gmail API after classic Hangouts is retired?

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API to:

1. list chat messages by calling `Users.messages: list` with query parameter `q="in:CHATS"`.
2. get chat messages by calling `Users.messages: get` with chat message ids.

Will both of these techniques continue to work for Hangouts chat messages, even after classic Hangouts is retired later in 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, I was able to query for chat messages that were in the new Hangouts but not in the old one. so I believe there should not be a problem after the old one is deprecated.